# text container size - text wrap?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how can I  wrap the text inside a container and not get cut off if the page size is smaller than the size needed for the paragraph to be displayed. - A scrollbar cannot be used..

Any helping ideas? :s

Comment: Please explain your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need try this:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Wrapping is automatically added to the word fit in the specified width of the block.

Comment: AlexPrinceton - I have a section the set to the size of the height of the window, now I have a container inside that for a description, but when the window is small the text gets cut off.

Comment: to adding the text did not appear scrolling not ask height unit that will contain the text ie the parent and child block must not be specified height

Comment: and looked to add text padding